# Using a font in flutter that is not in pubspec.yaml - can it be done?

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts

The application I'm getting ready to write using Flutter requires the user be able to choose any font that is on their computer. There is no way for me to anticipate what those fonts may be and I certainly would not have a license for many of them. So... my question is:

Can I write flutter code to select and use a font on the client's computer?

I've done many web searches and, as far as I can tell, the only way to use a font in Flutter is to put it in pubspec.yaml or if it exists in a google fonts file that I can't remember the exact name of. Either solution would not work for me. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at font loader class

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FontLoader-class.html

or if you are ok with using packages try

https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_cached_fonts

```
@override
void initState() {
  final DynamicCachedFonts dynamicCachedFont = DynamicCachedFonts(
    fontFamily: fontFamilyName, // The font family name to be passed to TextStyle.fontFamily
    url: fontUrl, // A valid url pointing to a font file (.ttf or .otf files only) 
  );
  dynamicCachedFont.load(); // Downloads the font, caches and loads it.

  super.initState();
}
...
Text(
  'Some Text',
  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: fontFamilyName),
)
```

Please note you may have to move the font to a url from where you can download this content. So you can make a service in firebase or any server which will upload the ttf and assign that url here in this package.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions. I'll take a look and report back on how it works out. the package seems to be aimed at web applications and this will be an application built for Windows and MacOS, but I'm assuming for now that the mention of "web fonts" doesn't exclude me using the same technique for desktop apps.

Comment: I think I may have answered my own question and been concerned about using fonts when there was nothing to be concerned about in the first place. 
I just assumed since I read about custom fonts and placing within pubspec.yaml as an asset that I could not specify any font within a TextSpan unless it was first included as an asset in flutter. 
That appears to not be the case. I just did several tests specifying several different and very unusual font families (like 'Comic Sans MS') and it worked just fine without first creating an asset for the font.

Comment: So... I guess the only reason for a custom font asset is simply to make sure that if I have a specific font (one that may not be included on someone's computer) that I want to use for my app, that I can load it as an asset and make it available even though the user's device/computer does not have that font.